# Internet Explorer 9 - webpage title (document.title) not showing on print

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, web, google-chrome-frame

I'm trying to get the webpage title to show up on a printed version of my website. I am targeting IE9 (with Chrome Frame installed). I have successfully changed the title with the following JavaScript

```
document.title = "my title";
```

I have confirmed this by seeing the title at the tab in IE9.

I'm assuming there are some security permissions set up that are messing with the page  title from being printed. I created a very small basic webpage locally that prints the webpage title correctly (changing the webpage title with the above JS), but what would prevent my more complex website from printing the document title? I've read around that some ActiveX settings could do this.

Another thing to note is that on my complex website the Print Preview option isn't there, when it is on the local simple website. Maybe this is related? Any input is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I did try resetting IE (which removes all data and add-ons), and to no avail. Here's sample code (for both the complex and local-simple site I made). Like I've said above, I have confirmed that the document.title can (and does) get changed, I'm just baffled as to why the page title isn't being printed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        $('#myDiv').on('click', function(){
            document.title = 'my custom title';
        });
    );      
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
I have still not found a solution to this, but after awhile I have determined that this is **an issue with Google Chrome Frame**. It turns out that Google Chrome Frame enabled on a page will mess up IE's printing functionality; specifically, it will not print any page headers/footers, date, current/total pages of printed website, or URL. When GCF is enabled on a page in IE9, Print Preview is no longer even a selection anymore - my guess is since GC handles what IE9 defines as Print and Print Preview in one screen, GCF just disables it.
I have added GCF as a tag on this post, and I'm not sure how to further solve my problem. I can say that GCF is clearly the problem here. Please message me if somebody else sees this and has the same problem

Comment: Show us more code. When do you call that javascript snippet?

Comment: The code is above, but that's not the primary issue. I have confirmed that the document.title can be changed successfully, I'm trying to figure out why the title doesn't get printed

Answer (score 0):

The layout of a printed page can be configured.

The title can be removed (exactly as the page number or the source-url)

There is nothing you can do against this.

Waht you can do is a CSS-resource for printing, that will show a special headlind (not title), that is only visible if printed.

Comment: [Page Boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-box-page-rule) deals with some of what _I think_ you are talking about, but it's not supported in IE9 (not even in Chrome yet). Thanks @Christian but I think this is a Chrome Frame issue. I'll explain in my OP